# VBA Date Format - month/day/year

Tags: vba, excel

I want to produce todays date like this: 01/23/2016 month/day/year.  I wrote the below code but the result is 23/01/2016. Can anyone help me? Thanks

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 9):

The code you use enters something into an Excel cell. Excel recognises that it is a date and will display the date according to the default settings.

In order to display the date with your preferred format, you need to format the **cell** that displays the date, not the data entry string.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = Date
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```